# Update table column based on another table values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
Table 1:

```
ID    TICKET_AGENT    ORIGINAL_ID 
1          0               5
2          0               3
3          0               1
4          0               2
```

And,
Table 2:

```
ID    TICKET_AGENT 
1          A               
2          C               
3          B               
4          B
```

Is there any scenario where I can use `UPDATE` to update `Table 1.TICKET_AGENT` field by searching through `ORIGINAL_ID` as the `ID` of `Table 2` and if `ORIGINAL_ID` is found in `table 2`, update `table 1` after with the corresponding `TICKET_AGENT` value?

UPDATE: ORIGINAL_ID points to ID in table 2

Comment: Does `Table1`.`Original_id` point to `Table2`.`id`? Or is it different?

Comment: @matigo yes, sorry forgot to mention that, will fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do a joined `update`

```
update table1
inner join table2 on table2.ID = table1.ORIGINAL_ID
set table1.TICKET_AGENT = table2.TICKET_AGENT
```